# Exporting with pd.to_csv to include both colname and rowname

Tags: python, export-to-csv, crosstab

I'm trying to export `pd.crosstab` results `to_csv`, and I rename column and row title, but only row name was successfully export to csv, and column name is missing. Anyone knows why?

My code:

```
f = pd.crosstab(df.var1, df.var2, rownames=['gain'], colnames=['loss'])
f.to_csv('dir', index = True)
```

What I get:

```
gain      A      B     C    
 A        0      2     1      
 B        2      5     1
 C        2      3     9
```

What I want:

```
loss      A      B     C   
gain      
 A        0      2     1      
 B        2      5     1
 C        2      3     9
```

Thanks!

SOLVED:

There's no direct way to add the column name to excel, so use `df.to_csv('output.csv', index_label = 'x|y')` to bypass that.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no clear cut solution to this problem, but there are workarounds. Hopefully this dupe will help you.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thx for helping me find this post. It's really helpful!